# How to do SIMD with array of Extended?

Tags: delphi, simd

I recently delved into the following Delphi source codes:

- [Extentia](http://www.tommesani.com/Download/Exentia.zip)
- [SIMDTest](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/obsolete/graphics/simdtest.zip)

To my understanding:

1. **SSE** is the way to go for doing SIMD with `Single`
2. whereas **SSE2** is the counterpart for `Double`

**My Question:**

Is there a way to do similar thing (SMID with array of Extended I mean) if I expect to benefit from more precision as `Extended` can provide ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extended is a FPU (x87) type, and a funky one that isn't found outside x87 CPUs.

SSE doesn't support values larger than double (so no quad (128-bit) either ).

Not even in SSE versions documented but not yet available (Ivy Bridge)

So no, this is not possible.

Further SSE2 also widens the registers and provides additional instructions, so "SSE vs SSE2" it is not just single vs double

Comment: True indeed, I noticed the warning in Embarcadero RAD Studio's help stating: `Extended offers greater precision than other real types, but is less portable. Be careful using Extended if you are creating data files to share across platforms`. So how can be SIMD greater precision without Extended attained? I firmly believe that there should be a solution.

Comment: Then I would dig in those sources (that say there should be a solution). I read the Intel datasheets and I found none.

Comment: Marco is right. All extant SIMD on x86 or x64 is with 4 and 8 byte data. Do you really need extended? I know I don't in my FEM code.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Ok. That reassured me (My box is based on a Pentium D processor). I prefered using Extended when doing WGS84 great circle computation and seeing overloaded function/procedure in Math.pas unit I thought it's worthwhile.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: It was just a personnal conviction. Thank you for pointing to the Intel datasheets. They are a must.

Comment: The `Extended` floating point type doesn't even exist in the Delphi 64-bit compiler; it simply becomes an alias of `Double`. Everyone else uses `Single` and `Double`.